# Why is my .gitleaks.toml config not picking up the fake secrets commited to this sample repo?

Tags: github, github-actions, gitleaks

Testing out Gitleaks on Github Actions here. Why is my .gitleaks.toml config not picking up the fake secrets committed to this sample repo?

Repo: https://github.com/xeonproc/fake_commited_secrets/actions/runs/8425848965/job/23072861994

Action Workflow:
https://github.com/xeonproc/fake_commited_secrets/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml

Example Github Action run:
https://github.com/xeonproc/fake_commited_secrets/actions/runs/8425848965/job/23072861994

Thanks for the tips!